# How to highlight the selected custom icon with raty

Tags: javascript, jquery, rating-system, raty

**Hello**,

I am using [raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty) with the iconRange option and i am wondering how i can only highlight the selected custom icon.

my code is

```
$(".ratySmiley").raty({
    starType: 'i',
    hints: ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous'],
    iconRange: [
        {range: 1, on: 'icon icon-nothappy', off: 'icon icon-nothappy'},
        {range: 2, on: 'icon icon-mehh', off: 'icon icon-mehh'},
        {range: 3, on: 'icon icon-nomood', off: 'icon icon-nomood'},
        {range: 4, on: 'icon icon-happy', off: 'icon icon-happy'},
        {range: 5, on: 'icon icon-veryhappy', off: 'icon icon-veryhappy'}
    ]
});
```

Following the documentation, i only found one example where the `single` option is set to true but it only works if your icons are the same...

If you know something about it please help me.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution**,

I wrote a little js function which add an `id = 'active'` to the clicked smiley so i can tune it with css later.

```
function clickHandle(element, event) {
    $(element).children().each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("id");
    });
    $(event.target).attr("id", "active");
}
```

Hope it can helps you.

Thomas